# Beach activities for 60 year old parents in Langkawi, Malaysia?

Tags: malaysia, beaches, activities

My parents are in their 60s and we are planning to bring them to Langkawi, Malaysia. I'm not sure what kind of activities they might enjoy over there, so, could you please suggest some.

**UPDATE**
They can't walk too much, my Mom enjoys gardening, I'm not sure about my dad, he spends most of his time watching lately. He likes to meet people though.

They don't travel much, so if I ask them, they will probably say anything or pretend to enjoy whatever we suggest (it happen), so I have no clue what they will enjoy.

Comment: @fretje, well, they can't walk too much, my Mom enjoy gardening, I'm not sure about my dad, he spend most of his time watching lately. They don't travel much, so if I ask them, they will probably say anything or pretend to enjoy whatever I suggest (it happen), so I have no clue what they will enjoy.

Comment: @fretje, hope it doesn't sound condescending anymore :) thx

Comment: It's better ;-)

Comment: Relaxing and peoplewatching. And maybe eating.

Comment: How did I missed this question earlier? :O

Answer (score 3):

There are many organized tours in Langkawi, but it really depends on how much your parents will be able to walk - or whether they would be even interested in seeing those places. Telaga Tujuh waterfall and Gunung Raya, while both having beautiful views, do involve a fair bit of walking and not through particularly comfortable trails at that. Places like Oriental Village would probably not interested your parents as much, as it's a place fairly targetted towards the Western travellers to the islands.

Relaxing on the beach and maybe going on boat rides are an option. Don't make it too boring for them! I'm sure there are tour operators you can speak to for going to specific sights that won't involve much walking, perhaps by hiring a private car for a bit extra. Maybe take them to one of the spas on the islands!

Answer (score 2):

I visited Langkawi in June 2011 and I have a few key suggestions relevant to you and your parents:

- I recommend **renting a car** - it is the most sensible way to get around the island, it's affordable, safe and generally easy to drive around. This is unlike any other island I visited in SE Asia. You can hire a car right at the airport and there are many options.
- Visit the **Langkawi Sky Bridge** (see photo below) - it has a stunning view of the jungle and there are lot of interesting attractions around the bridge. Its definitely a older parent type of activity.
- There's actually pretty awesome little [Go Kart track](http://www.langkawiattractions.com/Go-Kart-Circuit.php) near the airport which is really fun and affordable.
- The Telaga Tujuh Waterfalls are cool but are a pretty long 1 hour hike in the jungle.

[image: Langkawi Sky Bridge]